# ansible git Failed to checkout to branch

Tags: ansible

I have the below ansible task to clone a git branch. The problem is when there are some local changes below tasks throws error "Failed to checkout to branch_name"

```yaml
- name: Git pull fromremote
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ uname }}"
  git:
    repo: "{{ repo_url }}"
    dest: "{{ dest_dir }}"
    force: yes
    update: yes
    version: "{{ branch_name | default(master) }}"
```

> "cmd" : "/bin/git checkout --track -b branch_name" "Error" : "msg" : "Failed to checkout to xyz branch", "stderr" : "error" : "The following untracked working files would be overwritten by checkout\n Please move or remove them before you switch branches"\n "Aborting"

I tried the below unix command to do a force checkout which worked perfectly even with local changes

```
git checkout -f branch_name
```

Comment: try `git switch branch_name`

Comment: Does this happen only when you change branches between two checkouts? I was not able to reproduce using the same branch (i.e. run playbook, edit a file, run playbook again).

Comment: git switch and git checkout works as unix commands but problem is when i execute ansible git with force : yes option. I could not find switch option in git module . Probably ansible version is creating this problem as i see someone raised bug in github for same issue

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking at [the code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/git.py#L1018), and it looks as if the `force` option doesn't impact the `git checkout` command (it's used only in `git fetch`). It looks like Ansible only applies `--force` to `git checkout` when the branch already exists locally; the logic is:

```
if is_remote_branch(git_path, module, dest, remote, version):
    if depth and not is_local_branch(git_path, module, dest, version):
        # git clone --depth implies --single-branch, which makes
        # the checkout fail if the version changes
        # fetch the remote branch, to be able to check it out next
        set_remote_branch(git_path, module, dest, remote, version, depth)
    if not is_local_branch(git_path, module, dest, version):
        cmd = "%s checkout --track -b %s %s/%s" % (git_path, version, remote, version)
    else:
        (rc, out, err) = module.run_command("%s checkout --force %s" % (git_path, version), cwd=dest)
        if rc != 0:
            module.fail_json(msg="Failed to checkout branch %s" % version, stdout=out, stderr=err, rc=rc)
        cmd = "%s reset --hard %s/%s" % (git_path, remote, version)
else:
    cmd = "%s checkout --force %s" % (git_path, version)
```

I would call this buggy, or at best non-intuitive. Might be worth submitting a pull request to Ansible.

---

The workaround is probably to use the `command` module to explicitly run a `git checkout --force ...` command.

Comment: Thanks for detailed input. Even "cmd" : "/bin/git checkout --track -b branch_name" indicates "-f" proves further -f option is missing